# Cannot run iOS 15 Simulator on Xcode 15.0.1: Interrupted system call

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode15

I was trying to run iOS 15 Simulator on Xcode 15.0.1, but I got an error: "Unable to boot the Simulator. Interrupted system call"

I tried:

1. Reinstalling Xcode
2. Deleted "Derived Data"
3. Redownloaded iOS 15 runtime

None of the above methods works for me.

Here is the error log:

```
Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain
Code: 4
Failure Reason: Interrupted system call
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-10-26 16:42:13 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = "_IDEInstalliPhoneSimulatorWorker";
    Session = "com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.AA0321E3-E8C1-4B8D-A650-6078D711A67E";
}
--
Failed to start launchd_sim: could not bind to session, launchd_sim may have crashed or quit responding
Domain: com.apple.SimLaunchHostService.RequestError
Code: 4
--

Event Metadata: com.apple.dt.IDERunOperationWorkerFinished : {
    "device_model" = "iPhone13,1";
    "device_osBuild" = "15.0 (19A339)";
    "device_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "dvt_coredevice_version" = "348.1";
    "dvt_mobiledevice_version" = "1643.2.4";
    "launchSession_schemeCommand" = Run;
    "launchSession_state" = 1;
    "launchSession_targetArch" = arm64;
    "operation_duration_ms" = 213;
    "operation_errorCode" = 4;
    "operation_errorDomain" = NSPOSIXErrorDomain;
    "operation_errorWorker" = "_IDEInstalliPhoneSimulatorWorker";
    "operation_name" = IDERunOperationWorkerGroup;
    "param_debugger_attachToExtensions" = 0;
    "param_debugger_attachToXPC" = 1;
    "param_debugger_type" = 3;
    "param_destination_isProxy" = 0;
    "param_destination_platform" = "com.apple.platform.iphonesimulator";
    "param_diag_MainThreadChecker_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableDuringAttach" = 0;
    "param_diag_MallocStackLogging_enableForXPC" = 1;
    "param_diag_allowLocationSimulation" = 1;
    "param_diag_checker_tpc_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_gpu_frameCapture_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_shaderValidation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_gpu_validation_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_memoryGraphOnResourceException" = 0;
    "param_diag_queueDebugging_enable" = 1;
    "param_diag_runtimeProfile_generate" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_asan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_enable" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_tsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_sanitizer_ubsan_stopOnIssue" = 0;
    "param_diag_showNonLocalizedStrings" = 0;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_enabled" = 1;
    "param_diag_viewDebugging_insertDylibOnLaunch" = 1;
    "param_install_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_UID" = 2;
    "param_launcher_allowDeviceSensorReplayData" = 0;
    "param_launcher_kind" = 0;
    "param_launcher_style" = 0;
    "param_launcher_substyle" = 0;
    "param_runnable_appExtensionHostRunMode" = 0;
    "param_runnable_productType" = "com.apple.product-type.application";
    "param_structuredConsoleMode" = 1;
    "param_testing_launchedForTesting" = 0;
    "param_testing_suppressSimulatorApp" = 0;
    "param_testing_usingCLI" = 0;
    "sdk_canonicalName" = "iphonesimulator17.0";
    "sdk_osVersion" = "17.0";
    "sdk_variant" = iphonesimulator;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 14.0 (Build 23A344)
Xcode 15.0.1 (22266) (Build 15A507)
Timestamp: 2023-10-27T00:42:13+08:00
```

As you can see I'm running Xcode on my MacBook Pro 16 (M1 Max) with macOS Sonoma

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, answering my own question, after trying thousands of methods I've finally fixed it:

1. Close Xcode, type this command in terminal: `sudo chmod 1777 /tmp`
2. Clean the `dyld` folder in this path: `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator`
3. Restart Xcode, done!

Comment: Directory to delete is inside Caches: ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Caches/dyld